# Displaying XSLT content in Silverlight

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, controls

I am working with Silverlight 4.

I am supposed to display a XSLT inside a Silverlight page as is, read-only.

Which control is best suited for this?

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you want to display the XSLT stylesheet (an XML document) or the transformation's result (text/plain, text/html or XML)

Comment: I want to display result, HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT files are for transforming one file format to another (generally used for taking XML and creating other XML files or HTML pages or human-readable plain-text files out of the input XML). They are not visual documents - what you actually need is to display the result of an XSLT transformation and the control you need for that will depend on what type of file the output of the transformation is (e.g. it could be an HTML file or a text file).

If you can post an example XSLT file you need to use, we might be able to offer more detailed help.

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
extension-element-prefixes="date"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
In case of any problems please call our support desk.
Many thanks
</Div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: ><xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="Firstname"/>
<xsl:param name="Username"/>
<xsl:param name="Password"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<Div align="left">
Dear <xsl:value-of select="$Firstname"/>,
Thank you for registering with us!
Your login details:
Username:  <xsl:value-of select="$Username"/>
Password:  <xsl:value-of select="$Password"/>

Comment: Added the XSLT in 2 parts as comments didnt allow me to add full. The XSLT is used for sending email